# What is the difference between setScrollPosition & getTabAt methods of the TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, viewpagerindicator

What is the difference between `tabLayout.setScrollPosition(int, float, boolean);` and `tabLayout.getTabAt(int);` methods?

because, I can also set the `tabLayout` to indicate to the next by using `setScrollPosition`, but, the problem with this approach is that this Method does not update the Integer returned by `tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getTabAt : Returns the tab at the specified index.(TabLayout.Tab)

getSelectedTabPosition: Returns the position of the current selected tab. 
-selected tab position, or -1 if there isn't a selected tab.-

setScrollPosition :

```
void setScrollPosition (int position, 
                float positionOffset, 
                boolean updateSelectedText)
```

Set the scroll position of the tabs. This is useful for when the tabs are being displayed as part of a scrolling container such as ViewPager.

Calling this method does not update the selected tab, it is only used for drawing purposes.

position -> int: current scroll position

positionOffset -> float: Value from [0, 1) indicating the offset from position.

positionOffset -> boolean: Whether to update the text's selected state.

Comment: Can you please explain the setScrollPosition in more detail? like what are these three parameters that it takes?

Comment: @Nasib I've updated my answer and added more details